# How to make child rows column clickable?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML table in which there are child rows , I want to make those child rows column clickable to perform particular action.

I have parent rows and when I click on those rows, child rows are being shown, in which there is a column `col2` , on which when I click it should perform some action for each child rows column.

I want `col2` of child row to be clickable to show some more information using JavaScript and HTML. I don't know, but on click function(`onclick('col2')`) something like that can be helpfull or not??

```js
var $container = $("#container");
var $row = $("#container table tbody tr");

// Loop through items in JSON data..
var $button = $("<button>" + 'abc' + "</button>");
$container.prepend($button);
var table = $("<table>");
table.append($("<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th></tr>"));

// Button click handler..
$button.on("click", function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    // Replace row HTML..
    //parent row
    var row = $('<tr class="parent_row" ><td>' + 'data' + '</td>' + +'<td>' + "" + '</td></tr>');

    table.append(row);

    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      //child row
      var row = $('<tr style="display: none"><td>' + "" + '</td>' + '<td>' + 'data' + '</td></tr>');
      table.append(row);
    }
  }

  $("#table").html(table);
  $('.parent_row').click(function() {

    $(this).nextUntil(".parent_row").toggle();
  })
  // Show table if it's not already visible..


});
```

```css
table {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  width: 500px;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

button {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="table">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*.**

Comment: what should i do to make col2 clickable to show some information?

Comment: i am not getting what you are saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var $container = $("#container");
var $row = $("#container table tbody tr");

// Loop through items in JSON data..
var $button = $("<button>" + 'abc' + "</button>");
$container.prepend($button);
var table = $("<table>");
table.append($("<tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th></tr>"));

// Button click handler..
$button.on("click", function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

    // Replace row HTML..
    //parent row
    var row = $('<tr class="parent_row" ><td>' + 'data' + '</td>' + +'<td>' + "" + '</td></tr>');

    table.append(row);

    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      //child row
      var row = $('<tr style="display: none"><td>' + "" + '</td></tr>');
        $('<td>data</td>')
          .on('click', function() { alert('some action') })
          .appendTo(row);
      table.append(row);
    }
  }

  $("#table").html(table);
  $('.parent_row').click(function() {

    $(this).nextUntil(".parent_row").toggle();
  })
  // Show table if it's not already visible..


});
```

```css
table {
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  width: 500px;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

button {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="table">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I will try to implement your code into mine .

Answer (score 2):

To catch clicks on any column in a table, simply add a click listener to all cells in that column:

```js
const column2cells = document.querySelectorAll('#table tr>*:nth-child(2)');

for (const cell of column2cells) {
  cell.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(`You clicked cell [${cell.cellIndex}, ${cell.parentElement.rowIndex}] with content "${cell.textContent}"`);
  })
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Col 1</td>
      <td>Col 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As a note for the logging output: Remember `cellIndex` and `rowIndex` start at `0`, not at `1`.

Comment: thankyou , i will look to modify your code according to my need .

Answer (score 0):

You could give a specific class name to each `<td>` in col2 when you are creating them, and then using a regular `onclick` event based on that class name.

So:

```
var row = $('<tr class="parent_row" ><td>' + 'data' + '</td>' + +'<td class="col2">' + "" + '</td></tr>');
```

And then:

```
$(".col2").on("click", function() {
    //whatever you want to do here
});
```

Comment: @GauravBaghel You're welcome! If this helps, please consider upvoting. Have a good day!